# How do I prevent the Microsoft Text Driver (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) from changing the Current Directory (C# application)

Tags: c#, oledb

I have the following code that creates and opens an OleDbConnection object:

```cs
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\";", folder);
m_Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
m_Connection.Open();
```

The application can have many threads running simultaneously which access files using relative paths (bad, yes, I know).  During a *very* brief instant of this `Open()` call, the Current Directory is changed to the `folder` specified for the `Data Source` attribute in the connection string.

I say *very* brief because my procedure for verifying that `Open()` was the culprit involved a separate thread that examines `Environment.CurrentDirectory` in a while loop (started just before the `Open()` call and ended just after), and adds it to a List.  This test concluded that the Current Directory changed to `folder` between 0% and 2% of this time (yes, sometimes never).

So my real problem is that very intermittently another thread accesses a file using a relative path, and ends up throwing a `FileNotFoundException` that specifies a filename in the path used for the OleDbConnection `Open()` call.

The only options I can think of to fix this are to 1) not use the Microsoft Text Driver, 2) not use relative paths, or 3) synchronize all of the threads to ensure this call isn't occurring any time a call is made to open a filename that contains a relative path.  Any other ideas?

I also tried suspending all of the `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` (excluding the current thread) just before the `Open()` call, but that did not work (current thread was suspended when suspending a thread other than the current--I couldn't figure out why).  I figure this is probably not a good idea, anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: You could always store the current directory on start up and then use `Path.Combine` with the stored value and a relative path.

Comment: This is probably what I'll have to do.  Thanks.